# Mysql: Change Timezone Per Query

Tags: mysql

I want to change the timezone while a query is executing.

Like I am calculating attendance and I store timestamp in attendance table. Expected check-in time of a Employee is stored in employee table and Office timezone is stored in Office table, timezone can differ office by office. Office 1 can have different timezone from Office 2.

So functions like DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME()) Should work with each Office's Timezone.

Comment: You could have explained with some examples and table structure, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, You're right, But i was in little hurry. i will be editing this soon.

Comment: you need to store a datetime not a timestamp with value utc_timestamp then when you retrieve your date you apply your time delta

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the mysql function:

[Convert_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)